# Button on UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

i can create a button in tableview and i have a offers and in that offers i have products so i can generate all products as per offer in one table so i have a button to add cart when user add to cart it will show remove button its ok when i won't go to other view but when im came  back it  shows again add button so how can i get remove button after add and after came to this view please help me out thankyou

***Translation***

I want to create a button in a tableview. The button initial state should be 'Add to cart' and when the user clicks the button I want it to change to 'Remove'.

***Translation***

```
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(230, 25, 73, 40) ;
btn.tag = indexPath.row+1;
btn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];

for (int i=0;i<[[[productsArray valueForKey:@"product"] valueForKey:@"productId"]  count];  i++)
{ 


    BOOL status=FALSE;

    for (int j=0; j<[[appDelegate AddingCartArray]   count]; j++) 
    {

    NSString *pstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[productsArray valueForKey:@"product"] valueForKey:@"productId"] objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSLog(@"pstr %@",pstr);
    NSString *cstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[appDelegate AddingCartArray]valueForKey:@"productId"]  objectAtIndex:j]];
    NSLog(@"cstr %@",cstr);

        if([[[productsArray valueForKey:@"product"] valueForKey:@"productId"] objectAtIndex:i] == [[[appDelegate AddingCartArray]valueForKey:@"productId"]  objectAtIndex:j])

        {
            status =TRUE;
        }

    }
    if(status)
    {
        [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RemovetoCart.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(Remove:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }   



    else {
        [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"adtoCart.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(addCartClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }



}

[cell addSubview:btn];

[btn setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[btn release];
```

Comment: You could use some punctuation, eh?

Comment: I am guessing you are doing this is viewDidLoad

Comment: Nice deciphering job, @MichaelSmith.

Answer (score 0):

You should use method delegated from UITableView to add objects on UITableViewCell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell)
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
// your button code generation here and assigning touch event to it
    [cell.contentView addSubview:btn]
    return cell;
}
```

after that you can create method which receives touchUpInside event and sets to sender (UIButton *) nesessary properties such as color or text.

btw: you shouldn't use absolute values in frame generating. Use cell.contentView.frame property for creating button frame CGRect .